# How can I paint an area without color-matching after treating mold?

Tags: paint, mold

Is there a clear paint that I can use after I have treated an area for mold in the bathroom? I don't want to try and match the color.

Comment: Do you mean transparent paint?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Is the area a different color? Does it have a different sheen or gloss? Are you just trying to seal it?